# How to make permalink setting using laravel 4?

Tags: nginx, laravel-4, permalinks, laravel-routing

I am new to Laravel 4, I have project that required me to create "permalink settings feature" like in wordpress.

But the problem is I am using Laravel and Nginx, and .htaccess is not working on Nginx. Maybe I can use Laravel routing system to complete this task.

But can anyone tell me exactly how to do it using laravel routing system?

for example I have 2 different route settings:

**1. mydomain.com/post/first-post**

**2. mydomain.com/post?id=1**

Those routes should go to the sampe page but it depends on user settings. When user choose "**route setting 1**", the behaviour should be:

- When i type mydomain.com/post/first-post on browser address it should go to the first post page.
- But when i type mydomain.com/post?id=1 , it should go to mydomain.com/post/first-post also.

And vice versa if user choose "**route settings 2**"

Any suggestion on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I guess you're looking for the `URL::full()` method. Taken from the [Docs](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_full)

Comment: Thank you. That solve one of my problem, but how can I change route settings on the fly like Wordpress do? I mean my route settings can changed based on user preference.